# Creating IPA file in Xcode 5 for project containing static library sub-projects

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode5, ipa

I have a project which contains a sub-project to build a 3rd party static library the app depends on.

In Xcode 5, when I come to export an .ipa file after doing an Archive build and clicking the Distribute button in the Organizer window, the option "Save for Enterprise or Ad Hoc Deployment" is missing from the list of options (I only see "Submit to the iOS App Store" or "Export as Xcode Archive").

Does anyone know i) why this is and ii) how to rectify the problem?

For a simple test project (with no 3rd party static libraries) the option "Save for Enterprise or Ad Hoc Deployment" is there and works as expected.

Comment: Not sure but could the 3rd party library have been built for distribution only and not dev or test? At which point you would only be given the option to submit to the app store. This is only a guess

Comment: Andrew, did you resolve this? I was wondering if it was related to this: http://pulkitsinghal.blogspot.co.uk/2012/03/wrong-archive-ios-app-archive-vs.html

Comment: Close Pete - appreciate the help - but no cigar. Just worked out the real solution though, which I'll post as the answer below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The solution to this problem is to select the project file of the included static library, select Build Phases, then **delete the Copy Headers build phase** using the (x) button on the right hand side.

Do Product >> Clean Build Folder (hold down Alt to get this option), then Product >> Archive, you will then get the option to "Save for Enterprise or Ad Hoc Distribution" when you click the Distribute button within the Organizer.

Comment: This worked for me in Archive, but then when running the dependent project in debug, I get a load of linker errors

Comment: @wkhatch - try removing/re-adding the link against the library in the outer project's Build Phases.

Comment: thanks Andrew. I ended up adding a Copy Files phase instead, instead of the original Copy Headers... and that resolved my issue