# Unable to both Archive and run in debug with framework project dependency in xcode5 workspace

Tags: xcode, xcode5

I've got a workspace containing an iOS app project, which is dependent on another framework project, also in the workspace. I ran into issues with Archive while building for distribution, where the resulting output was unusable for creating an .ipa. Googling turned up this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19630755/creating-ipa-file-in-xcode-5-for-project-containing-static-library-sub-projects), where you delete the Copy Headers phase from the framework project, and which worked for getting the Archive exported and submitted, but now when I go back to running the app project in debug, I'm failing builds due to missing header files from the framework project again. So, what is the proper way to configure everything so I can both archive and run in debug without having to go through all this nonsense? I mean really, I'd think this would be pretty typical.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up replacing the previously deleted Copy Headers phase within the framework project, with a Copy Files phase, and that did the trick.